# Cannot import name getoutput

Tags: python, import, youtube

So I'm trying a script for YouTube views increaser; when I try to run it with:

```
$ python youtube.py [visits] [youtubeLinks.txt] [minWatch] [maxWatch]
```

I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call list)
File "youtube.py", line 5, in <module>
from subprocess import getoutput as shell
ImportError: cannot import name getoutput
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html)

> In Python 3.x, getstatus() and two undocumented functions (mk2arg() and mkarg()) have been removed. Also, getstatusoutput() and getoutput() have been moved to the subprocess module.

The script was written for python3 and you're running python2. Change the

```
from subprocess import getoutput as shell
```

to

```
from commands import getoutput as shell
```

Or install Python3 and run it using that since Python2 is deprecated at this point and you might face more issues running the script

Comment: But when i type "python3 --version" it says i have version 3.7.6

Comment: are you running the script using the `python3` command though? `python3 youtube.py ...`